# How to get iCloud keychain back after update to iOS 8?

Tags: ios, icloud, keychain

I have upgraded my devices to iOS 8. All seemed well. However, today I noticed I was mising some password in Safari. Checking my iCloud settings, I noticed that keychain was turned off. This must have happened during the update. Trying to enable it, I had to authorize via a second device. No problem I thought. But no, my iPad also had the same problem.
So now iCloud wants my security code, which I had set more than ayear ago, and cannot remember. What now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a verified phone number and have set up the ability to verify devices using SMS verification code, you can use this method. Otherwise, you will not be able to recover your keychain yourself. You may find help by contacting Apple: http://www.apple.com/support/icloud/contact/

Comment: Since I was missing only one new password, I reset the keychain and synced it freshly from my iPhone. But it is really a shame that the iOS upgrade broke the keychain settings.